# Need to create a function for a casino game

Tags: c++

I have a Project for my programming class, and its requiring me to set up the main functionality for the casino using functions.

First, I needed to seed the random number generator which I think I did right.

```
void seedRand(int seed)
{
srand(time(0));
}
```

Second, was to continue to set up functions. So I set the next one to print out numbers to the second decimal place.

```
void printMoney(double money)
{
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
}
```

The next one, and the one I'm not understanding, is to have the user pay, and have the casino receive the money.
Sorry if i didn't put enough information, if something is missing please ask. I'm still new to understanding everything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
void payMoney(double & wallet, double amount)
{

}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to print the actual value here: `std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << money;`?

Comment: I believe, from what i was told, when the function is call and i put the value in the parameter for print money it will output in the form of currency. i.e

Comment: printMoney(5);

the output would be :
5.00

Comment: But you don't print the value? Why passing it as parameter then? _"rintMoney(5); the output would be : 5.00"_ Nope!

Comment: probably seeding shout take the actual `seed` into account

Comment: For `payMoney`, should you subract the `amount` from the wallet?  It's been a long time since I used subtraction, perhaps you could show me?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to understand , I know its not as simple as :
    
    void payMoney(double & wallet, double amount)
    {
    payMoney = wallet - amount;
    }
The whole point was make this function able to manipulate whatever amount the user requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which I think I did right.

No you didn't, it should rather look like

```
void seedRand(int seed) {
    srand(seed == 0?time(0):seed);
}
```

If there's a parameter passed, it's probably meant to be actually used. I've chosen zero as a convention, when `seed()` should be called with a randomly time based value.

> So I set the next one to print out numbers to the second decimal place.

Your second function sets up the output stream state well, but misses to output the value, it should look like

```
void printMoney(double money) {
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << money << std:: endl;
                                                    // ^^^^^
}
```

And at least your last function is probably supposed to be implemented as

```
void payMoney(double & wallet, double amount) {
    wallet -= amount;
}
```

---

All in all it's hard to answer what you're supposed to do with this task.

But since you tagged this question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I'd rather recommend to go putting these functions in context of classes like `class Casino` and `class Player`.

```
class Casino;
class Player {
    double wallet;
public:
    void payMoney(Casino& Casino, double amount);
};

class Casino {
public:
    void addToBank(double money) {
        bank += money;
    }
private:
    double bank;
};

void Player::payMoney(Casino& casino, double amount) {
    wallet -= amount;
    casino.addToBank(amount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you give me a run down of how you came up with seeding the random number generator?

also, is it really 
wallet = wallet - amount? or wallet -= amount?